Can this property that I formulated be used to find solutions to Navier Stokes in cylindrical coordinates?
Let's say I want to derive a vortex flow function $$\psi (r,t)$$ using a scalar field bell surface of the form below, where $W(t)$ controls the width (but is not actually the width) as a function of time, $H$ is the bell's height, and $\alpha$ is an arbitrary constant.
$$\psi (r,t) = He^{-\frac{r^2}{\alpha W^2}}$$
Given that, $r=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$
Assume that $H$ is the angular velocity around which the vortex's critical radius rotates, and $W(t)$ is a function that governs the radial evolution.
To derive a tangential velocity function, we first need the partial derivative of $\psi (r,t)$. If we treat $t$ as a constant, then we can graph $\psi (r)$ in two dimensions.
$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}=-\frac{2Hr}{\alpha W^2}exp\left ( -\frac{r^2}{\alpha W^2} \right )$$
Secondly, the width of the bell surface is some unknown $q$. To find $q$, we substitute all $r$ for $q$ in,
$$0=\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial r^2}$$
and solve for q.
$$0= \frac{\partial^2 \psi }{\partial r^2}|_{r=q} = -\frac{2H}{\alpha W^2}\left[e^{-\frac{q^2}{\alpha W^2}}-\frac{2q^2}{\alpha \:W^2}e^{-\frac{q^2}{\alpha \:W^2}}\right]$$
And the critical radius q becomes, $$q=\sqrt{\:\frac{\alpha W^2}{2}}$$
Note that for $\alpha = 2$ then, $q=W$
Thirdly, I assume that the azimuthal velocity is scaled by a constant of proportionality, $k$ in vector field, $$\vec{v}=\left< 0, v_{\theta }, 0 \right>$$
$$v_{\theta }=k\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial r}$$
And $k$ is the ratio to the tangential velocity $v_{\perp } = \omega r = Hq$ and the slope of $\psi (r)$ when $r=q$.
$$k=\frac{Hq}{\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial r}|_{r=q}}$$
$$Hq=k\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial r}|_{r=q=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha W^2}{2}}}$$
$$k=-\frac{\alpha W^2\sqrt{e}}{2}$$
Lastly, substitute $k$ into $v_{\theta }=k\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial r}$ and you will find that for all values of $\alpha$, $t$, and $H$,
$$v_{\theta }=k\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial r} = r\sqrt{e}\psi (r,t)$$
Applying this to a flow function I derived from the disk method of integration and circulation identities,
$$\psi \left(r,t \right)=\frac{w_{0}R_{0}^{2}}{R(t)^{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{r^2}{R(t)^{2}}\right)}$$
The azimuthal velocity component is simply,
$$v_\theta = r\sqrt{e}\psi (r,t) = r\sqrt{e}\frac{w_{0}R_{0}^{2}}{R(t)^{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{r^2}{R(t)^{2}}\right)}$$
I'm not sure if this procedure is fallacious or useful in finding the azimuthal velocity. I have yet to figure out how to use the vorticity transport equation to derive the vorticity vector, $\vec{w}_{\hat{z}}$ and its material derivative. The continuity equation that excludes fluid density for $\psi (x,y,t)$ is,
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{u} = \frac{\partial u_x }{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u_y }{\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 \psi  }{\partial x \partial y} - \frac{\partial^2 \psi  }{\partial y \partial x}=0$$

Hi, can you please reformat your question as I did by embracing your math with Latex tokens?

I just loosely read through and didn't find anywhere wrong. You could also provide the potential expression $\phi(r,t)$ in addition to the stream function $\psi (r,t)$ for more readers to understand easily.
